# Modify field names in serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have an object I'd like to serialize using DRF's serializers, but I'd like to normalize some field names. I thought I might be able to use the `source` attribute to achieve this:

```
user = { 'FirstName': 'John', 'LastName': 'Doe' }

serialized = UserSerializer(data=user)

class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source="FirstName")
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source="LastName")
```

However, I'm not sure how to access the data object passed in - is there a way without creating a new method or some kind of complex `super()` call?

**edit:**

Use case: I'm hitting an API which returns values in CamelCase ('FirstName', 'LastName' etc) which I need to validate and modify key names to snake case. I was hoping I could use a standalone serializer, and transform the names in the serializer. I don't have a model for the data that must be transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with properties on your Django model:

```
class Foo(models.model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    @property
    def sanitized_bar(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self.bar.lower()



    @sanitized_bar.setter
    def sanitized_bar(self, value):
        self.bar = value.lower()

class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   bar = CharField(source='sanitized_bar')
```

Doing it this way gives you sanitized control on your DB if you need to use those models in management commands or elsewhere, in addition to your DRF interface.

You can also do a pre-save hook:

```
class Foo(models.model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.bar:
            self.bar = self.bar.lower()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That makes sense - but what is this is not a model serializer? I assume the `source` attribute is not the way to achieve this..

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to do: `f = Foo();  f.sanitized_bar = 'baz'`.  The alternative is to implement a pre-save hook, but you would then have to save the model instance before it could be used.  You could also make `bar` be the property and shadow it with `bar_private` so the names are less confusing.

Comment: Okay.. I was hoping there was a simple solution I was missing - I'll look into switching things around, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    FirstName = serializers.CharField(source="first_name")
    LastName = serializers.CharField(source="last_name")
```

serializing:

```
class Person:
    first_name = "first name"
    last_name = "last name"

person1 = Person()
serialized_data = UserSerializer(person1).data # = {"FirstName": "first name", "LastName": "last name"}
```

deserializing:

```
data = { 'FirstName': 'John', 'LastName': 'Doe' }
serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
valid_deserialized_data = serializer.validated_data # = { 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe' }
```

Comment: This seems useful - but I was under the impression that the fields in the serializer should be my desired field names - not the other way around. I've added a use case to the question that hopefully clarifies. Can I still declare my serializer fields in snake case with your answer?

Comment: drf tries to get the value for each field using the declared name in the serializer, so you have to name the fields based on the names in the returned data of that API.